# jQuery and TinyMCE 3.5.2: attr() not working

Tags: jquery, tinymce

There's a problem in how jQuery and TinyMCE interact when using the jQuery version of TinyMCE that's been reported and solved several times. It involves, as I understand it, a redefinition of the jQuery attr() function by TinyMCE.

The result is that the while the following returns the attribute value when TinyMCE is not being used on a page:

```
var junk = $(this).attr('someAttribute');
```

an object gets returned instead when TinyMCE is in use.

I'm running into this problem with jQuery 1.7.2 and TinyMCE 3.5.2.

Is anyone else encountering this? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: You can try `$(this).prop('someAttribute');`

Comment: Thanx, Joy, but that doesn't change anything. The call is still returning an object when tinyMCE is in use.

Comment: i strongly advise everyone not to use the jQuery build of tinymce. it is slow and a source for problems. it is better to use the regular tinymce build and load the standard jQuery lib too

Answer (score 3):

TinyMCE jquery's plugin would break jQuery's `attr` method (jQuery>=1.7.2.). This is fixed in TinyMCE 3.5b3.

For your references, here is a reported [TinyMCE Bug #5136](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=5316) and a [fix](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/commit/dc97bc56ca4350fd45d8a076423e59c6a40fe2c5).

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting an answer to this question, but if anyone has a different solution I'd still love to hear it.

Basically, I took Thariama's advice and stopped using the jQuery build of tinyMCE. Instead, I did the following:

```
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "tinymce",
        script_url: '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")',
        theme: "advanced",
        plugins: "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",
        convert_urls: 0, // default 1
        content_css: '@Url.Content("~/Content/tinymce.css")'
    });
```

This was based on a suggested solution I found elsewhere on StackOverflow.

FYI for others converting from the jQuery version of tinyMCE: you need to remember to add the mode: and editor_selector: parameters to the parameter list you were using previously. If you don't you'll get the default behavior of turning every textarea control into a tinyMCE editor.

You'll also need to include the tinyMCE library in your page's header. In my application that looks like the following:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Enjoy!